# JComboBox error when items are added

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, jcombobox

I try to add some items to a `JComboBox` and I receive a `NullPointerException` error. 
This is a sample of my code :

```
public adminPanel() {
        fillComboTeacher();
        initComponents();
    }
    public void fillComboTeacher(){
        HashSet<Person> set = cont1.returnTeachers();
        Iterator it = set.iterator();
        try {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Person p = (Person) it.next();
                String name = p.getName();
                comboTeacher.addItem(name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Person class - name, state (with getters and setters)

returnTeachers() - returns a `HashSet` containing Persons with state = "Teacher"

I don't understand why I'm receiving this error and why I can't fill the `ComboBox`, I followed a tutorial step-by-step and something is still not well.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you are calling `fillComboTeacher` before calling `initComponents`. I assumed that you initialize `comboTeacher` in the latter. Is it the case? If yes, just swap the two method calls in the `adminPanel` constructor.

Comment: Oh .. great!That was the problem, Haha.. Thanks @ZouZou

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `fillComboTeacher` before calling `initComponents`.

Looking at the method's name, I assumed that you initialized `comboTeacher` in the latter.

So at that point (`comboTeacher.addItem(name);`), `comboTeacher` is not yet initialized and hence the `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, just swap the two method calls in the constructor to initialize your components before trying to use them.

Few notes:

- A `NullPointerException` is often easy to fix. Just look at the stacktrace (it indicates the line where the NPE occurs) and see what can be null and why at this line.
- Don't use a raw iterator, but a generic one (`Iterator<Person> it = set.iterator();`), that will avoid you to cast the object returned by a `next()` call.
- Since you are only reading the elements in the set, you can simply use a for-each loop `for(Person p : cont1.returnTeachers()) comboTeacher.addItem(p.getName());`